# What information do I need to give an external dev team to access and upload files to my Amazon S3 account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm new to Amazon S3, and do not want to give more information than is necessary for the team to whom I'm outsourcing a project. They are building an image hosting site, and would need access to my S3 credentials - what exactly would the devs need to have access to? Just my Access Key ID?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They'll need an Access Key ID & corresponding Secret Access Key.

You can generate a unique one for them to use via the Security Credentials Page in the Account section of the website.

When they're done, you can delete there key and make a different one to use for the live site.  Just make sure that when they develop the app they put the key information in a configuration file so you can change it when they're done.

Comment: Just to see if I get this straight: I just need to "create a new Access Key" in the "Access Keys" tab in the Security Credentials page, correct? I'm assuming that doing this will render the old Access Key ID / Secret Access Key useless.

Comment: This will not make the old Access Key useless.  You can have more than one.  The idea here is that you can make "throw away" keys for different purposes (like giving to dev teams) while keeping other keys active for longer periods of time.